# Order of Requests in ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to download some data.

I have the following in a  method:

```
// Request 1
request1.tag = 1;
[request1 setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];

// Request 2
request2.tag = 2;
[request2 setDelegate:self];
[request2 startAsynchronous];

// Call third request method
[self callThirdRequest];
```

Now from within `callThirdRequest`, I am grabbing some data that has been downloaded from `request2` and in there, I am calling `startAsynchronous`. The reason I have the calling of the third request in a separate method is because it will get invoked more than once. After putting some console outputs, it seems that `callThirdRequest` is being invoked before `request2` starts its download. Therefore, when `callThirdRequest` tries to grab some data which should have been downloaded by `request2`, it does not work as there is no data.

Why is that? How can I make sure `callThirdRequest` is only called when `request2` is done downloading?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request is run asynchronously, the rest of your code will continue to run at the same time. Your first two requests are doing exactly that. You have two options.

You can run the second request synchronously. (Not a good idea, since your app will appear "frozen" until the second request completes. Also, using this method won't help you if the second request, in your list of three, fails.)

A much better idea would be to use delegate callback methods. This is the better way of dealing with this, for two reasons. First of all, you can handle failed requests properly, and also, you can handle successful requests properly. Yu want something like this:

```
// Request 2
request2.tag = 2;
[request2 setDelegate:self];
[request2 startAsynchronous];



- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
   if(request.tag == 2){
     [self callThirdRequest];
   }
}
```

Make sure to check the request in the delegate callback, to ensure that it's the "second" one, so that you don't end up firing the wrong action at the wrong time. In this case, I used the "tag" property of the request. If you would have retained the request as a property of your class, you can just check for that as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Thanks! My third request gets called several times to download some data. At the end, I'd like to open up a window. How would I determine when the last request has been called?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, it may be easy to determine based on the nature of the data. You could obviously use the delegate callback and check for a `tag` of 3, but you'd still need to know when that's the last call.

Comment: Would it be better to make the third request a synchronous call then and set up the window when the download has ended? I'm not sure if that would work since the third request is run a few times.

Comment: I am able to determine beforehand how many times the third request will run. From that, how do I determine to set up the window in `requestFinished`?

Comment: Store the number of times beforehand. Then, in your class keep a counter (or a static variable in the delegate method, even). In the delegate method, increment said counter when a request matching the tag of the third request object (the third request) finishes. When the counter hits the target number of requests, call whatever code you want.

Answer (score 1):

That is because request2 is running asynchronous. You should start the 3rd request in the request-did-finish-delegate-method of request2!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `startAsynchronous`. An asynchronous call will operate on another thread.  You need to set the delegate on request2 and then call the third request when request2 is finished.

```
    // Request 2
    request2.tag = 2;
    [request2 setDelegate:self];
    [request2 startAsynchronous];

...

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [self callThirdRequest];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I also have a request that is called several times. At the last call, I'd like to set up a window. How do I determine when the last time the request is called?